# Constructing a morphism out of a family of morphisms of algebraic varieties

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I have the following problem: let $X$ be a $K$-variety (a geometrically irreducibe $K$-scheme of finite type over, say, a number field $K$).
Let $\phi_i:Y_i\rightarrow X$ be a family of dominant morphisms  with $Y_i$ $K$-varieties of same dimension of $X$.

Is there a way to construct a morphism $\phi:Y\rightarrow X$ from a $K$-variety $Y$ also of same dimension of $X$ such that the images of the $K$-rational points of the $Y_i$'s are all contained in the image of the ones of $Y$?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Why can't you take $Y = X$?

Comment: Because my next question would be, if all the $\phi_i$ have degree $\geq 2$, can I construct $\phi$ also of degree $\geq 2$?

Comment: Take $Y = X \sqcup X$.

Comment: that's not irreducible, is it?

Comment: It is not, of course. If you want irreducible, you can take $Y = X \times Spec(K[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: @Hoot: was in OP's definition something about reducedness?

Comment: @Sasha Ah, it does help to actually read the question. A non-reduced variety, yikes! My fault.

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, by a $K$- variety i don't mean just something geometrically irreducible, but geometrically integral! sorry